# Calculate the total number of equivalence classes

Tags: prime-numbers

> Let $P$ be the set of all primes. Define a relation in $P$ by $x\sim y$ if $x+y$ is even. It turns out that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Calculate the total number of equivalence classes.

The only even prime is 2, so we can consider all the cases without 2 such that the sum of 2 prime numbers must be even.

Comment: i realize that the only even prime number is 2. So we can just simply consider all the cases without 2 such that the sum of 2 prime numbers must be even.

Comment: Next time just add your attempts into the post, I did it for you already for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of two numbers is even if either, the two numbers are both even, or they are both odd.

$2$ is the only even prime.   So the only prime to which $2$ can be added to yield an even number, is itself.   Thus $\{2\}$ is one equivalence class.
$${[2]}_\sim= \{2\}$$

$3$ is an odd prime number.   What primes are there to which adding $3$ yields an even number?   That gives you the equivalence class of ${[3]}_\sim$.

Now, take a prime that is not in either ${[2]}_\sim$ or ${[3]}_\sim$, and repeat the process until you run out of primes.

> Already done?   That was quick, wasn't it. 
>
>  $$\{\{2\}, \{3,5,7,11,\ldots\}\}$$

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and clear explanation!

Comment: That means the number of equivalence class is only 2? 
the 2 classes are {2} and {3,5,7,11,13,17,19,...} ,right?

Comment: That is what it means. @RotCiv